# Reflection and transmission coefficients

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, scattering, refraction, dielectric

Suppose we have a plane wave with s-polarization travelling through a medium with refractive index $n_1$ in direction $\vec{k}$ perpendicular to a surface of a dieletric with refractive index $n_2$; at a distance $L$ fram the surface of separation between $n_1$ and $n_2$ there is a third dielectric $n_3$ (all the separation surfaces are parallel to each other). Suppose $n_3<n_1,n_2$, but we don't know any relation between $n_1$ and $n_2$. Suppose every medium is lossless, so all refractive indeces are real quantities. (see figure below)

[image]

At each of the separation surfaces, the electric field is in part reflected and in part transmitted, so we define the quantities $r_i,t_i$ ($i=1,2$) by
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
E_{r_i}=r_iE_{in}\\
E_{t_i}=t_iE_{in}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
In our case, these coefficients are related to the refractive indeces by
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
& r_1=\frac{n_1-n_2}{n_1+n_2}\\
& t_1=\frac{2n_1}{n_1+n_2}=1+r_1\\
& r_2=\frac{n_2-n_3}{n_2+n_3}\\
& t_2=\frac{2n_1}{n_1+n_2}=1+r_2\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

In the case $n_1>n_2$, we get that $r_1>0$, so $t_1>1$, so by definition $E_{t,1}>E_{in}$. Can this happen and why?

By considering all possible internal reflections, how can you evaluate the total reflection and transmission coefficients $R$ and $T$?

Comment: Short answer: yes, it's possible, it's the transmitted power that should be less than the incident one . Hint: consider the Poynting vector. To evaluate the total transmission and reflection coefficients, the quickest approach is to use the so-called transmission line analog of the stratified media. Unfortunately I don't have the time to write a complete answer.